# ASP.net style sheet + postion of web controls

Tags: asp.net, css

I am a novice at website building. I downloaded a free css from a website and applied it to my project. Here's a screen shot

http://www.csstemplatesweb.com/wp-content/uploads/wpsc/product_images/get_educated_scr.jpg.

I dragged and dropped some ASP web controls(buttons and labels) on the page(using absolute positioning) from the toolbox. Now I want to my web controls to stay within the text area of the template(the area with the pic of guys wid a laptop) and not float away on resizing and when I run the web page on different resolutions. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a containing div in your markup and work from there. Honestly, there is no short cut to understanding something like CSS, you either study up or you don't.

Comment: I had created a div tag using a css class but it didnt help

Comment: Can you provide some markup showing exactly where you're having the problem? Maybe I can help you position one control and you can take it from there. Alternatively, supply a link to the template itself.

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning. Use the Firefox Web Developer tool to help you identify the CSS elements you are interested in.

Comment: http://www.csstemplatesweb.com/products-page/css-templates/page/4/
template name - get educated. You need to register and login to download and here's the body.
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    </div id = "content">
    <div >
   <asp:Button ID="submitbutton" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 321px; position: absolute;
                 top: 166px" Text="Submit" />
        </div> 
        <div id="footer"><p>Copyright <a href="http://www.csstemplatesweb.com">Csstemplatesweb.com</a> - 2008</p></div> 
    </form>
    
</body>

Comment: Your markup was malformed. I've cleaned it up, and removed the absolute positioning. I've added some left-padding to the button which you can tweak:

<body>  
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
<div id="container">  
<div id="header"></header>  

<div id="content">
</div>  

<div style="padding-left:100px;">  
<asp:Button ID="submitbutton" runat="server" Text="Submit" />  
</div> 

</container>

<div id="footer">
<p>Copyright <a href="http://csstemplatesweb.com">Csstemplatesweb.com &copy;2008</a></p>
</div> 

</form>  
</body>